# Codeigniter Library layer over model (Abstraction or Encapsulation)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've recently been asked to add Todo and Notification systems to a project I've been working on for a music school e.g. when a tutor books a holiday it will trigger a "Todo" to find cover for the lesson, if cover is found it removed the "Todo".

My question is should I be putting triggers for the Todo and notifications in the models just before the database has been updated or should I use a Library as a kind of layer between the controllers and the models?

Using it as a layer I would be having the same functionality as model, however, instead of having:

```
//Model
function add($params) {
    //add tutor to database
    $this->db->*blabla*;
}
```

I would have:

```
//Library
function add($params) {
     $this->load->model('tutors');
     //Do something before add
     $this->tutors->add($params);
     //Do something after add
}
```

Would/should I be doing something like this and adding a layer between the model and the controller to abstract functionality or is it acceptable/standard to encapsulate other models and functionality inside a model?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can retreive the db object in your library by

```
get_instance()->db->*blabla*
```

But this is not the best practice. You should create all you databases query in your model and use your model in your controller/library

Comment: I have already built the application and yeah all the db connections are done with models. The client is now going into the next iteration of the project, so my question was more about refactoring i.e. should I add a layer between the model and the controller to abstract functionality or is it acceptable/standard to encapsulate other models and functionality inside a model.